# How to render column conditionally for ActiveAdmin `table_for` array collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, arb

I have an array `versions` that I render on ActiveAdmin custom page (`.html.arb`), and I need to show some columns depending on the array element's value, but I struggle to understand how to loop over this array and apply conditional rendering

```
table_for versions do |element|
   ...
   column 'Example' if element == value
   ...
end
```

`element` class, in this case, is `ActiveAdmin::Views::TableFor` which is logical, but I can't understand how I can access `versions` items in this loop as their original class (`Integer`), so my `element` would be `Integer` too. Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hello implementation of table_for is not supporting it,
I suggest you to create partials and pick it by name using your conditional logic  instead

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can hide a column. For example:

̣```
if $("td.col.col-grado").text() == "0.0".repeat($("td.col.col-grado").length)
$("th.col.col-grado").hide()
$("td.col.col-grado").hide()
if $("td.co.col-botella").text == ""
$("th.col.col-botella").hide()
$("td.col.col-botella").hide()